# Best Testing tool for testing ExtJs application that can be easily automated on a Continuous Integration server

Tags: testing, extjs, continuous-integration, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am new to the Testing Arena. I am working with a very heavy ExtJs application. 
And I am looking for the best testing tool.
I came across a bunch of tools, but can't seem to make a decision.

1) [Siesta](http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/)    2) [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/)    3) [Riatest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest.html)

I want to be able to deploy these tests easily on a CI server.
Siesta and Jasmine can both be used with PhantomJs to automate the tests, but which one is better and easy to use?
As long as I can generate various clicks correctly and capture output, I'm cool.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Our company is moving from a Java based client to an ExtJS web and mobile application. We use QTP/UFT for Java automation which is slow, buggy, expensive, and cannot get passed the DOM easily so I started investigating Siesta recently. It seems like a viable option in my book but I admit I haven't checked out the other applications.

The initial setup with Siesta took longer than expected but with its event recorder, it makes it a gratifying transition. The recorder still requires debugging. I'm in QA and know how to script using Python, Bash, etc but it's definitely a learning curve to transition from VBScript to ExtJs/Siesta JavaScript. They have an open source version and a free 45 day trial to check out.

I've read about HTML Robot and [SmartBear](http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/?_ga=1.10447349.1362197236.1363803531). Here's a [post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265719-Test-Automation-support-for-ExtJS-applications) on the Sencha forums that talks about different automation software. Sencha also plans to release some kind of [automation involving SenchaCmd](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289432-Sencha-Cmd-support-for-Jasmine-tests) during SenchaCon 2015 this April 7 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a tool which covers your needs and improve the software quality.

Jasmine is good for unit tests without much gui interaction, you should use this to test your domain logic (e.g. stores, models, ...). Jasmine can run on every environment, a simple server with nodejs runtime is enought.

For regression tests the choice is yours. What tool you are comfortable with? Choosing a tool is one part, using it is another. Riatest seems like a windows application, are you able to run this on your CI server?

Evaluate them with your dev team and then make a choice for the long run.